# Default LXTerrminal Vim Toggle Paste problem

Tags: raspbian, lxterminal

I have my `.vimrc` config with toggle paste lines included:

```
set pastetoggle=<F3>
```

But when I try to press <kbd>F3</kbd> it types `<F3>` into file and nothing happens (I expect it to switch mode to `INSERT(PASTE)`).

Comment: `vim --version` ?

Comment: Have you tried it when you are in insert mode?

Comment: When I'm in the `INSERT` mode, then I have <F3> as an output from keyboard instead of toggling paste mode.

Comment: @Fabian it's 7.4

Comment: Have you found a solution? Do you access lxterminal remotely by SSH from a Mac? Or local? If you don't mind please post your complete `.vimrc`, I'd like to test it. Is it Raspbian Stretch?